# Instagram API - Can you retrieve the Time spent from the Your Activity section?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want to fetch the user Activity logs from the API - to be more specific I want to fetch the user data for the Activity section.

Here's the link to the help center to see what I am talking about:

iPhone:
https://help.instagram.com/195902884574087/?cms_platform=iphone-app&helpref=platform_switcher

Android:
https://help.instagram.com/195902884574087/?cms_platform=android-app&helpref=platform_switcher

Web:
**This is still not available on the web version**

But I could not see that anywhere on their documentation pages, so I am unsure if this data is hidden somewhere in the other [APIs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram).